# Calculate similarity of 1-row dataframe and a large dataframe with the same columns in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, similarity

I have a very large dataframe (millions of rows) and every time I am getting a 1-row dataframe with the same columns.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,-1], 'c': [-1,0.4,31]})
input = pd.DataFrame([[11, -0.44, 4]], columns=list('abc'))
```

I would like to calculate cosine similarity between the input and the whole df.
I am using the following:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
df.apply(lambda row: 1 - cosine(row, input), axis=1)
```

But it's a bit slow. Tried with swifter package, and it seems to run faster.
Please advise what is the best practice for such a task, do it like this or change to another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't do matrix manipulation with `DataFrame` but with `numpy.array`. So I will first convert them

```
df_npy = df.values
input_npy = input.values
```

And then I don't want to use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` so I will take care of the calculation myself, which is to first normalize each of the vectors

```
df_npy = df_npy / np.linalg.norm(df_npy, axis=1, keepdims=True)
input_npy = input_npy / np.linalg.norm(input_npy, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

And then matrix multiply them together

```
df_npy @ input_npy.T
```

which will give you

```
array([[0.213],
       [0.524],
       [0.431]])
```

The reason I don't want to use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` is that it only takes care of one pair of vector at a time, but in the way I show, it takes care of all at the same time.

Comment: Why not using swifter?

Comment: Because I have never heard of that. I should check it out later.